# How to rotate a triangle to look at a point?

Tags: vector, mesh, trigonometry

Lets say I have a triangle defined by 3 vertices and a center point, how do I rotate the triangle so its normal is looking at a specified point?

Answer (score 2):

Given points A, B and C of a triangle, the normal of the triangle is the cross product **AB**×**AC** (or possibly **AC**×**AB** depending on the vertex order). If the point on the triangle is M and the point towards which to look is P, you then have an infinite number of rotations that cause **AB**×**AC** to be in the direction of **MP**. The shortest rotation of them all can be computed using a [quaternion from two vectors](http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/09/18/beautiful-maths-quaternion-from-vectors) method. The final tranformation is therefore:

- subtract M from all triangle points so that the triangle centre is at the origin
- rotate all points using the quaternion described above
- re-add M to all triangle points

In pseudocode:

```
tranform = translate(OM) * rotate(quaternion(cross(AB,AC), MP) * translate(MO)
```

Comment: Could you explain translate(OM)? Im new to game dev and unity!

Comment: It is a translation along **OM**, which is a vector that goes from the origin to M. If these are difficult concepts for you, I suggest starting with some simple [Unity3D tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).